# How can I initialize a custom GUI class?

Tags: objective-c, class, user-interface, initialization

I'm developing an iPad app.

Now I ran into the following problem. I created a "Custom Class" for a `UIScrollView`. So in my nib file I have added a default `UIScrollView` and set the `Custom Class` to **MultiSelectView** (which is the custom class I created). Screenshot [here](http://i51.tinypic.com/2nq4rae.png).

So in my **MultiSelectView** I have added some methods that I want to use. This works!

The issue is that I'm wondering how I can initialize certain objects that I need in these methods. It seems like `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {}` is not called, and neither is `- (void) viewDidLoad {}`.

Thus, is there a way to initialize a custom (GUI) class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you unarchive a view from a .xib file, it is not sent `-initWithFrame:`, as you've noticed. Instead, it's sent `-initWithCoder:`.

So, if you've got any UIView subclass in a .xib file that needs custom initialization, you'll need to override `-initWithCoder:` as well as (or instead of) `-initWithFrame:`.

Comment: Tnx! Implementing the `-initWithCoder:` method did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `initWithCoder`, it is called when object is loaded from NIB

Or, better, `awakeFromNib`. The difference is that `awakeFromNib` is called when all outlets are connected.